# how do i filter UITableView using NSPredicate and UISegmentedControl

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nspredicate, uisegmentedcontrol

first thing i did was add `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *statusControl;` to my .h file and synthesized it in my .m file
then i linked the following code to my segment controller on the storyboard as well as the IBOutlet i mentioned earlier

```
-(IBAction)indexChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    switch (statusControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            selectedStatus = @"ALL";


            NSLog(@"ALL");
            break;
        case 1:{
            selectedStatus = @"NEW";

            NSPredicate *new= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.STATUS contains[c] NEW"];
            listOfEstNetGrand = [[listOfEstNetGrand filteredArrayUsingPredicate:new] mutableCopy];

            NSLog(@"NEW");
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            selectedStatus = @"COMPLETED";

            NSPredicate *completed = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.STATUS contains[c] COMPLETED"];
            listOfEstNetGrand = [[listOfEstNetGrand filteredArrayUsingPredicate:completed] mutableCopy];

            NSLog(@"COMPLETED");
            break;
        }

    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

i ran debugging and i got a crash here `listOfEstNetGrand = [[listOfEstNetGrand filteredArrayUsingPredicate:new] mutableCopy];`

without code, im logging the correct NSLog so i know the buttons work, but i cannot filter my uitableview. what am i doing wrong?

any help would be appreciated. thanks

edit: heres the crash I'm getting `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CactusQueue 0x13ce87800> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key COMPLETED.'*** First throw call stack:`

edit 2: i changed my code to `NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"STATUS contains[cd] COMPLETED"];` and it worked. not sure why since i use `SELF.` when searching

Comment: Please add the crash message as another "code" section.

Comment: sorry, i added it after posting, guess my ninja edit wasnt quick enough

Comment: No worries; just a text edit.  I can't help on the problem, but I can help you make this look better for those who can.  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your predicate should be like

```
NSPredicate *completed = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.STATUS contains[c] 'COMPLETED'"];
```

or

```
NSPredicate *completed = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.STATUS contains[c] %@",@"COMPLETED"];
```

Note the ' for value you supplied. Otherwise predicate will consider it as a property Of the object

Comment: thanks for your help, i was able to fix it myself with something stupid. i updated my post to reflect.

Comment: your way works too so I've marked your post as an answer